# How to change Template's route by conditions in Controller?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I'm a newbie using cakephp-3.0.

I'm planing to show different templates-views according to user's browser/agent.
In cakephp2.x the code can be like below:

```
if ($this->DisplayModeService->hasSpViewSupport()) {
    App::build([
        'View' => [APP . 'View/SmartPhone/', APP . 'View/'],
    ]);
}
```

but in cakephp3.0 it's in app.php :

```
return [
    'App' => [
        'paths' => [
            'templates' => [
                APP . 'Template' . DS . 'SmartPhone' . DS,
                APP . 'Template' . DS, 
            ],
        ],
    ],
  ];
```

But I want to change the template route only if the page has smartPhone version. 
In the case above it jump into SP version anyway.
(for I wanna keep the same name for the same page )

ex:

/Template/SmartPhone/profile.ctp, /Template/profile.ctp.(has SP/PC Version)

/Template/news.ctp (PC Version only)

can it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

You would better use $this->request->is('mobile'), and Themes